# A set of lines, each of which intersect the others, are either coplanar or share a single common point.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, induction, euclidean-geometry, solid-geometry

> Prove that a set of lines, each of which intersect the others, are either coplanar or share a single common point.
>
> Source: Hadamard

This is a surprisingly difficult problem, because it requires ping-ponging back and forth between two dissimilar concepts: *lines being coplanar* and *lines sharing a common point*.

I could not find a way to unify these two concepts, so instead developed the proof below, to which I request verification and feedback.  Is the proof correct? Is it well written (I tried to provide sufficient detail while being succinct)? Is there an alternate or simpler solution?

---

**Proof:** Let $S$ be a set of lines all of which share a common point $A$.  If line $\ell$ does not include point $A$, but still intersects every line in $S$, then $S \cup \{\ell\}$ must be coplanar.  Indeed, there is a unique plane $P$ containing $\ell$ and $A$, and since every line in $S$ includes two points on $P$ (the line's point of intersection with $\ell$ and the point $A$), every line in $S$ lies within $P$.

Furthermore, if $S$ is a set of coplanar lines, all lying in plane $P$, that do not share a [edit: delete *single*] common point, and $\ell$ intersects every line in $S$, then $\ell$ must also lie in $P$.  Indeed, there must be at least two distinct points where $\ell$ intersects a line from $S$, and since both these points are on $\ell$ and in plane $P$, then $\ell$ lies in $P$.

The claim therefore follows by induction, starting from the trivial case of [*edit:*] **any two lines** [previously was: *the empty set*].

---

As requested, below is the original problem from Hadamard, in the original French, taken from *[Leçons De Géométrie Élémentaire, Volume 2](https://archive.org/details/leonsdegomtriel01hadagoog/page/6/mode/2up), Livre V, Page 6, Problème 423*:

[image]

Comment: In the second part of your proof, you are assuming that $|S|\ge2$.

Comment: @AnneBauval I believe the fact that $S$ is a set of lines that do not share a single common point implies that $|S| \geq 2$.  (It is for that reason I made no mention of $|S|$.)  Do you agree?

Comment: Arguably, the single line doesn't satisfy "share a single common point", because it "shares infinitely many common points, which are points on the line itself". I do have a preference to start the induction with $|S| \geq 2$.

Comment: @CalvinLin There exists a point $A$ such that every line $s$ in the empty set includes $A$.  Likewise, for any singleton set, there exists such a point.  But I'll concede that by the very fact that we're having this discussion, the proof could be improved to be made more clear.  How would you recommend revising it?

Comment: I edited to clarify that my issue is with the word "single", not that "there exists a point". $\quad$ In terms of how to revise it, I suggest starting the induction with $|S| \geq 2$ like Anne implied, to avoid these issues.

Comment: One more remark: that "either or" is false if $|S|=2$. Two lines which intersect are coplanar *and* share a single common point. Can you please give a precise reference for Hadamard's original statement (in French, I guess), so that we can check?

Comment: @AnneBauval Original French posted.  I didn't intend the "either or" to imply exclusive or.  If the problem can be translated better, please make the edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So your translation "either or" (which generally means exclusive or, even if you didn't intend it) was faithful, so I won't correct it, although I find Hadamard's original formulation guilty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First notice that "either or" is false, it should be an inclusive or: a set $S$ of lines which share a single common point *can* be coplanar (and even *must* be, if $|S|=2$).

Your proof looks fine now, but here is a variant without induction:

Let $S$ be your set of (at least two) lines, each of which intersects the others. Let $\ell_1,\ell_2$ be two of them, sharing a point $A$ and lying in a plane $P$.

Assume that not all lines of $S$ contain $A$, and let us prove that all lines of $S$ lie in $P$. Let $\ell_3$ be a line in $S$ which does not contain $A$. Then, the three lines $\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3$ don't share a common point. In particular, $\ell_3$ lies in $P$ since it contains two distinct points of $P$: one in $\ell_1$ and one in $\ell_2$. Therefore, for every $\ell\in S$, $\ell$ meets their union $\ell_1\cup\ell_2\cup\ell_3$ in at least two distinct points. Again, since these points lie in $P$, so does $\ell$.